# Set Accelerator programmatically

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, gtk#

I'm currently developing an application in Mono, where I would like to set the accelerator keys to the menu via code (because I would like to change them depending of the selected language).

How do I realize this point? I can see that a menu item has an attribute "AccelPath" but how do I set it correctly?

Comment: Has no one any idea? I really would like to know how to set an accelerator to the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find it out myself. Just add a "_" before the label and you will get an accelerator.

Just one more thing is, if you relabel the action, this accelerator gets lost.